# How can I get control based on absolute coordinates in android system?

Tags: android, coordinates

I know the absolute coordinates after user touches screen on activity in Android system. How can I find control based on absolute coordinates in android system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two methods of the class [`android.view.View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) will give you the absolute coordinates in pixels

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getX()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getY()